# Getting an application_calculate event to run

Tags: vba, excel

We have an AddIn to get data from Sun Financials. It uses Sendkeys so we get the problem of NumLock randomly turning off. 
Data is retrieved from Sun when the worksheet/book is recalculated.

I have VBA to turn NumLock back on if it's turned off, but how can I get it to run in any workbook I have open?

I tried putting an Application_Calculate in Personal.xlsb ThisWorkbook but it doesn't run.

How can I get it to run?

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Sub Application_Calculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyNumlock) And 1) = False Then SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
End Sub
```

PS Putting it into the ThisWorkbook outside of personal.xlsb isn't an option, there's thousands of files it needs to work on plus they don't like workbooks with VBA in (company policy).

Comment: Is Numlock set per workbook? It's possible to have it on when "Workbook A" is active, but if you go to workbook "B" it's not?  Why not just call that macro from the SendKeys one?

Comment: The VBA with SendKeys is in a locked AddIn. It's not a case of it being on or off in different workbooks, it just randomly switches off when you type something into a cell.

Comment: Right - I'm just not quite sure what your question is?  How do you get this to run on any workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working, by placing the following code into ThisWorkbook in Personal.xlsb

Bizarre. or not. It now works, but it's not worked until everything was correct. Here's what I've got:-

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Set App = Application
If CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyNumlock) And 1) = False Then SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
Private Sub App_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

So, when I hit F9 or change a cell, NumLock turns back on.

One stightly bizarre but useful feature is that the Undo list is preserved! I was expecting to have to restore it once I'd got the Numlock bit working, but as the VBA is only doing a Sendkey and not flagging anything as changing from within the VBA Excel miraculously isn't emptying the Undo or Redo list.  So the maxim that VBA always empties the Undo/Redo lists isn't true.